# In cribbage, during the play, what is the count for four 5s in a row?

Tags: cribbage, scoring

If the person to the left of the dealer starts play with a 5, the next person plays a 5, the third person plays a 5 and finally, the dealer plays a 5, what is the count for the dealer?  Obviously the count is 20 and the points would be 12 because of four-of-a- kind.  But within that, could the 15s add up another 8 points (four combinations of 15 for two)?

Answer (score 6):

- Player 1 plays a 5 - Total = 5 - No Points
- Player 2 plays a 5 - Total= 10 - Two Points to player 2 for a pair
- Player 3 plays a 5 - Total = 15 - Player 3 get 8 points (2 for the 15 total, and six for the triple)
- Player 4 plays a 5 - Total = 20 - Player 4 get 12 points for the four of a kind.

Nice if you can get it :)

Answer (score 5):

During play you don't count 15s for card combinations, only for the total count.  So the third person got two points for making the total count 15, but the dealer only gets the 12 points for the four of a kind.  In the same way, if the lead was a three, followed by a king, followed by a 5, the person playing the 5 would not score any points for the play.